# Css footer problems with bootstrap navigation

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm recreating my layout with bootstrap because I want my website to be responsive.
I have my layout like this now:

```
<div id="container">
    <div id="header">...</div>
    <div id="content">...</div>
    <div id="footer">...</div>
</div>
```

This is the css code for container and the footer:

```
div#container {
position:relative; /* needed for footer positioning*/
margin:0 auto; /* center, not in IE5 */
height:auto !important; /* real browsers */
height:100%; /* IE6: treaded as min-height*/
min-height:100%; /* real browsers */
}

div#content{
padding: 0 0 4em; /* Footer height padding */
}

div#footer{
bottom: 0;
position:absolute;
z-index:0;
background:#000000;
left:0;
right:0;
margin-left:auto;
margin-right:auto;
}
```

But I got a problem (You can see the current code + setup right [here](http://marcvale.nl/v2/index.html)):
Once I resize the page like the footer is right under the header (it's on top of the content area text, I need to put the right padding in there). After that click the menu icon (in mobile view) and the footer is on top of the menu, which isn't meant to be so.

Just like this:
[image: My problem]

What's supposed to happen is that the menu is above the footer.

I tried fixing it with z-index:-20; but then I can't click the links in the footer anymore... So that solution won't work.

Can you help me?

Comment: If you're using z-index, you have to position the element. So try to add position: relative; and z-index: 1; to your #header. This should solve your problem.

Comment: you may want to use a min-height too, and maybe a different footer content for different resolutions, like you did to your top-menu

Comment: @MichaB Can you expand on this a bit?

Comment: @Patrick I will do that later, but this has to be fixed first.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't inspect your code correct. Just add z-index: 1; to .navbar and it should work. Don't think about the footer, you want the navigation to be at the top layer so add z-index to it.

Comment: @MichaB this worked perfectly! If you can create a answer below I'll accept it as the right one. Edit: Do you also know why the footer can overlap the 'content area' but  not my header?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should add z-index to your nav-bar, like so:

```
.navbar {
  ...
  z-index: 1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

for `div#footer` footer give `z-index=-1` and you will get it like this [image]

Comment: But then I won't be able to click any links in the footer (or the text which is there atm).

Comment: @Marc y the user wants to open the nav bar and click something in the footer?

Comment: If the footer got z-index: -1 you can't click anything even if the nav isn't open.

Comment: Just like @MichaB said.

Comment: @Marc check weather your nav bar is open if open then make your z-index=-1 else make it z-index=0; for your footer.

Answer (score 0):

To fix this problem :

1. It's better to Use ( header, content, footer) in separate container.
2. In line (42) in your style.css file your code should be like this:

***UPDATE***

the new code and make at least the footer in a separate container.

```
    div#footer {
       bottom: 0;
       background: #000000;
       margin-left: auto;
       margin-right: auto;
    }
```

hope this will help you.

Comment: If I do this the text from the footer will still be on top of the menu. Also the footer is not anymore at the bottom of the page.

Answer (score 0):

Answered by: MichaB

The solution was to add z-index:1; to the navbar. This fixed the problem.